# Spring embedded ldap server Unable to perform the search

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-ldap

I am getting below error while using spring embedded ldap server.

Your login attempt was not successful, try again.

> Reason: [LDAP: error code 32 - Unable to perform the search because base entry 'ou=people,dc=example,dc=com' does not exist in the server.]; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - Unable to perform the search because base entry 'ou=people,dc=example,dc=com' does not exist in the server.]; remaining name 'ou=people'

**Below are my code**

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ldap-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.unboundid</groupId>
            <artifactId>unboundid-ldapsdk</artifactId>
        </dependency> <!-- This is the ldap server-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    dn: ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com
    objectclass: top
    objectclass: organizationalUnit
    ou: groups

    dn: ou=people,dc=example,dc=com
    objectclass: top
    objectclass: organizationalUnit
    ou: people

    dn: uid=vandna,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com
    objectclass: top
    objectclass: person
    objectclass: organizationalPerson
    objectclass: inetOrgPerson
    cn: vandna bhimjiyani
    sn: bhimjiyani
    uid: vandna
    userPassword: password

    dn: uid=kaushik,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com
    objectclass: top
    objectclass: person
    objectclass: organizationalPerson
    objectclass: inetOrgPerson
    cn: kaushik andani
    sn: andani
    uid: kaushik
    userPassword: password

    dn: cn=user,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com
    objectclass: top
    objectclass: groupOfNames
    cn: user
    uniqueMember: uid=vandna,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com

    dn: cn=admin,ou=groups,dc=nascent,dc=com
    objectclass: top
    objectclass: groupOfNames
    cn: admin
    uniqueMember: uid=kaushik,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com
```

**in WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter**

```
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.ldapAuthentication()
                    .userSearchBase("ou=people")
                    .userSearchFilter("(uid={0})").groupSearchBase("ou=groups")
                    .groupSearchFilter("(member={0})")
                    .contextSource().root("dc=nascent,dc=com")
                    .ldif("src/main/resources/users.ldif");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Added top entry in .ldif file

> `dn: dc=example,dc=com
>   objectclass: top
>   objectclass: domain
>   objectclass: extensibleObject
>   dc: nascent`

change in WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

> ```
>       @Override
>   public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
>     auth
>             .ldapAuthentication()
>             .userDnPatterns("uid={0},ou=people")
>             .groupSearchBase("ou=groups")
>             .contextSource()
>             .url("ldap://localhost:8399/dc=example,dc=com")
>             .and()
>             .passwordCompare()
>             .passwordAttribute("userPassword");
>   }
> ```

.ldif file path is set in application.properties

> `spring.ldap.embedded.ldif=classpath:users.ldif
>   spring.ldap.embedded.base-dn=dc=example,dc=com
>   spring.ldap.embedded.port=8389`